# Display the type of triangle

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the problem:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/what-type-of-triangle/problem

I've tried this solution:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN (A+B) <= C OR (B+C) <= A OR (C+A) <= B THEN 'Not A Triangle'
        WHEN A = C OR A = B OR B = C THEN 'Isoceles'
        WHEN A = C AND A = B THEN 'Equilateral'
        ELSE 'Scalene'
    END 
FROM TRIANGLES;
```

**The above solution does not work.**

**Whereas the solution given below works**

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN A >= (B + C) OR B >= (A + C) OR C >= (A + B) THEN 'Not A Triangle'
        WHEN A = B AND A = C THEN 'Equilateral'
        WHEN A = B OR B = C OR A = C THEN 'Isosceles'
        ELSE 'Scalene'
    END
FROM TRIANGLES;
```

**I feel both solutions are the same except swapping the side of the operands while I also appropriately changed the operator so as to not change the meaning. Can someone please explain why solution 1 doesn't work?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
case
when A + B <= C or  C + A <= B or C + B <= A then 'Not A Triangle'
when A = B and B = C then 'Equilateral'
when A <> B and B <> C  and A <> C then 'Scalene'
when (A = B and C <> A) or (A = C and B <> A) or (B = C and A <> C) then 'Isosceles' END
from Triangles;
```

- Simple Case for each situation
- The order here is important for accurate results
- Important: <**=** condition is not clearly shown in Hacker rank question for 'Not a Triangle', This may be your issue

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing to do with which direction of the operator and sides of the operands you are using. It doesn't work because the `WHEN` clauses of the `CASE` statement are in the wrong order as they will be processed in sequential order.

You have the order:

```sql
WHEN A = C OR A = B OR B = C THEN 'Isoceles'
WHEN A = C AND A = B THEN 'Equilateral'
```

Then if `A = C AND A = B` is true then `A = C OR A = B OR B = C` will also be true so all Equilateral triangles will be matched as Isoceles.

If you swap the order of those statements:

```
WHEN A = C AND A = B THEN 'Equilateral'
WHEN A = C OR A = B OR B = C THEN 'Isoceles'
```

Then it will work.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dc3b1f52537693f0cd685d4015d7bcc4)*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN (A+B) <= C OR (B+C) <= A OR (C+A) <= B THEN 'Not A Triangle'
        WHEN (A = C and A<>B) OR (A = B AND A<>C) OR (B = C AND B<>A) THEN 'Isosceles'
        WHEN A = C AND A = B THEN 'Equilateral'
        ELSE 'Scalene'
    END 
FROM TRIANGLES;
```